# How update order

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is my table:

```
ID    int (Primary Key)
Name
Order
```

I'm trying move up/down my rows. So I want to update Order field.

```
UPDATE Technology 
SET Order = Order + 1 
WHERE ID = 2;
```

Comment: can you further explain your question

Comment: And provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: do you want to increase every rows order by 1 is it?

Comment: I want change Order=Order+1; It is okay. But when I did it one order same with another order.

Comment: make sure that Order is a datatype that can do addition, i.e. SET Order = convert(varchar(max),convert(int,Order) +1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have problem with column name `order`. `order` is a keyword so you can't use it directly. Try this way:

```
Update Technology set [Order]=[Order]+1 Where ID=2
```

---

Try this:

```
update menu
set [order]=m2.[order]+1
from menu  
join menu m2 on menu.[Order]= m2.[Order]-1
```

Comment: I did it. But there are two rows where Order are same. And I want first Order=Order+1 and Order=Order-1 another column

Comment: @AzadCebiyev how should they be orderd when this happens

Comment: @AzadCebiyev should be increase and decrease? Could be like this: `[Order]=[Order]+ID` ?

Comment: @AzadCebiyev You said that you have two rows where order the same. But MenuA:Order=1 and MenuB:Order=2 aren't not the same.

Comment: @AzadCebiyev can you show us what do you have in Technology and what result you expect?

Comment: When MenuA Order=1 change to Order=2 || MenuB Order=2 change to Order=1

Comment: @AzadCebiyev So do you want to replace them each other?

Comment: @Parado Yes replace order

Comment: @AzadCebiyev In your table there are only two rows: MenuA and  MenuB_

Comment: @Parado  no. There are many.

Comment: @AzadCebiyev How do we know you have to change order for MenuA and MenuB not for example MenuB with MenuC and MenuA wit MenuD ?

Comment: @Parado no yes a=b+1; b=c+1 ; c=d+1; a&b; b&c; c&d Only this

Comment: @AzadCebiyev I've updated the answer, try the solution please.

Answer (score 1):

OK, assuming that you want to do a swap operation between two items, you can change the logic in your SET clause.

```
--table setup
CREATE TABLE #Technology
(
 Id int,
  [Order] int,
  Name varchar(10)

)

INSERT INTO
    #Technology
    (
        Id,
        [Order],
        Name
    )
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Menu1'),
    (2, 2, 'Menu2'),
    (0, 0, 'Menu0'),
    (3, 3, 'Menu3')

--proof of original order
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Technology

UPDATE
    #Technology
SET
    [Order] =
    (
        SELECT
            [Order]
        FROM
            #Technology T1
        WHERE
            Id IN (1, 2)
            AND #Technology.Id <> T1.Id -- get the order of the *other* item in the pair
    ) -- this subquery works because we only have two ids do work with
WHERE
    Id IN (1, 2)

--new order
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Technology
```

<del>To make sure you get all rows where the order is already greater than the order you have for ID 2, you'll need a different where clause.</del>

<del>UPDATE Technology
    SET [Order] = [Order] + 1
    WHERE [Order] >=
    (
        SELECT [Order]
        FROM Technology
        WHERE ID = 2
    )</del>

<del>This will ensure that there are no duplicated orderings (if one didn't exist already).</del>

Comment: MenuA:Order=1 and MenuB:Order=2. When MenuB:Order=1 || MenuA:Order=2

Comment: @AzadCebiyev: I actually have no clue what that means. Please edit your question to be (much) more descriptive about your goals.

Comment: @AnonymousDownvoter: Why?

Comment: It is menu. I want move up/down menu.

Comment: @PeterMajeed sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: in MenuA Order=1 and in MenuB Order=2; When MenuA Order=2 after this MenuB Order=1;

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: Np - thanks for checking in again!

Comment: @AzadCebiyev: Thanks for the attempt at clarification. So, it looks like you want to *swap* the order of two items (MenuA/MenuB)?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes yes. When MenuA Order=1 change to Order=2 || MenuB Order=2 change to Order=1

Answer (score 0):

Because you are updating just one record, the one with ID=2, then obviously it will have the same `order` number as (I assume) the record with ID=3.

You ***probably*** want to increment ALL `order` numbers, for ALL IDs. Then you won't have duplicate order numbers in your table. To do that, just run your query without the `WHERE` clause.

```
Update Technology 
set Order=Order+1
```

Comment: No. Example: MenuA:Order=1 and MenuB:Order=2. When MenuB:Order=1 || MenuA:Order=2

Comment: @AzadCebiyev Well, this clears things up a *bit*.. You can add more details to the question about your problem, like what is the context. It would help a lot for us to understand what problem the solution is for. Then, maybe, we could probably provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think from your comments that you want to swap two orders. I'd probably do this with a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC swapOrders @order1 int, @order2 int
AS BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Technology WHERE order = @order1)
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Technology WHERE order = @order2)
        RETURN    --if either of the orders aren't valid don't do anything. You may want to log or raise an error here
    ELSE
        UPDATE Technology
        SET order = CASE order WHEN @order1 THEN @order2 WHEN @order2 THEN @order1 ELSE order END
END
```

This is assuming order is unique